# MAC OS - Terminal command to set JAR program to run at startup?

Tags: macos, boot, java, jar

This is where MAC OS stores its start-up items,

/Library/LaunchAgents

How to set a JAR program from Terminal to run at startup? Also how to remove existing program from startup?

Answer (score 0):

In recent version of Mac OSX `Start up` items are associated with a user's login information:

- Open `System Preferences` > `Users & Groups` > `User ID` (your nickname on the right)
- Now select the `Login items` tab .

You can now add or remove items from the list.

Removal is simple: Just select the list item you want remove and press the `-` button

To add the jar as a startup item, you'll need to create a wrapper shell script, set the permissions to allow `execute`, and then add it by pressing `+` and selecting the script.